# GSON throwing null pointer exception when a field is missing in json

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

GSON throwing null pointer exception when a field is missing in json

ReviewClass:

```
public class ReviewClass
{
private String name;

private List<Review> reviews;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Review> getReviews() {
    return reviews;
}

public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
    this.reviews = reviews;
}
}

class Review {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Main code:

```
ReviewClass reviewResults = gson.fromJson(reader, ReviewClass.class);
System.out.println(reviewResults.getReviews().get(0).getName());
```

JSON(no review field):

```
 {"itemId":978998,"name":"Palet","salePrice":15.88,"upc":"708431191570","categoryPath":"Toys}
```

So, the GSON throwing null pointer exception when there is no "reviews" field in json. PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 0):

Gson is correctly returning a `null` value for `getReviews()` since there aren't any reviews in the JSON. It is your `println()` call that is causing the NPE, because you cannot call `.get(0)` on `null`.

Add a null-check before your `println()`, e.g.

```
if (reviewResults.getReviews() != null) {
  System.out.println(reviewResults.getReviews().get(0).getName());
}
```

Alternatively have your `getReviews()` method return a non-null `List` when `reviews` is `null`.